# Tkinter Label referring to variable doesn't update when variable changed

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I have a problem with tkinter when a label refers to a value and I update the value by pressing a button. The value is indeed updated but the label text referring to this value is not.

How can I change this code that the button updates the value and the label refering to this value is updated and shown in the `root`?

```
import tkinter

root = Tk()
root.title('Test Button')
root.geometry('600x450')


class Letter:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


class Label:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.a_label = tkinter.Label(root, text=current_letter.value)
        self.a_label.grid(row=2, column=1)

class Button:
    def __init__(self, master):

    self.Button1 = tkinter.Button(master, height = 12, width = 24,
                                  command= self.update_letter)
    self.Button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def update_letter(self):
        current_letter.value
        print("current_letter.value before: " + str(current_letter.value))
        current_letter.value += 1
        print("current_letter.value now: " + str(current_letter.value))
        root.update

#initialize a
a = Letter(0)
current_letter = a

b = Button(root)
l = Label(root)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. First of all, you don't really need to create seperate classes for label and button in your program. You can create them inside of main class as `tkinter` widgets. Then if you want to pass a variable of an instance of some class, you need to initiliaze it and pass to your `update_letter` function properly, which you can use `lambda`. 
Here is an example code that you can work on:

```
import tkinter as tk


class UpdateLabel:


  def __init__(self, master):
      self.master = master
      # Create instance of Letter class
      a = Letter(value=0)
      current_letter = a
      self.update_button = tk.Button(master, text='Update', command=lambda:self.update_letter(current_letter))
      self.update_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

      self.label = tk.Label(master, text='No Value')
      self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)

  def update_letter(self, current_letter):
      print("current_letter.value before: " + str(current_letter.value))
      current_letter.value += 1
      print("current_letter.value now: " + str(current_letter.value))
      self.label.configure(text='Value: {}'.format(current_letter.value))

class Letter:
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = UpdateLabel(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

In that link [How to change label text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126015/7965185), you can find other options for changing a text in `tkinter label` widget.
I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

My, what a big button you have.

If you use a tkinter `Variable`, then updating it will automatically change what's in any widgets that refers to one of them. Here's some [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) describing them, and here's some [more](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) describing how to use them.

Here's how that could be done to the code in your question:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Test Button')
root.geometry('600x450')


class Letter:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = tkinter.IntVar(value=value)  # Store in a tkinter Variable.


class Label:
    def __init__(self, master, letter):
        self.a_label = tkinter.Label(master, textvariable=letter.value)
        self.a_label.grid(row=2, column=1)


class Button:
    def __init__(self, master, letter):
        self.letter = letter
        self.Button1 = tkinter.Button(master, height=12, width=24,
                                      command=self.update_letter)
        self.Button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def update_letter(self):
        current_value = self.letter.value.get()
        print("letter.value before: " + str(current_value))
        self.letter.value.set(self.letter.value.get() + 1)
        print("letter.value now: " + str(self.letter.value.get()))


# initialize a
a = Letter(0)

b = Button(root, a)
l = Label(root, a)

root.mainloop()
```

**A comment:** I found having your own classes named the same as those in `tkinter` a bit confusing because, while they superficially seem similar, they are actually *very* different—which could lead to difficult-to-understand programming errors.

Comment: sorry @martineau, but in your example the tk variable its an attribute of an object , would it work a-having value as just a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you did not update the label `l` after you have updated `current_letter`.  The simple solution is to change `current_letter` to `IntVar` and update class `Label` and `Button` as below:

```
class MyLabel:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.a_label = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=current_letter)
        self.a_label.grid(row=2, column=1)

class MyButton:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.Button1 = tkinter.Button(master, height = 12, width = 24,
                                      command= self.update_letter)
        self.Button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def update_letter(self):
        value = current_letter.get()
        print("current_letter.value before: ", value)
        value += 1
        print("current_letter.value now: ", value)
        current_letter.set(value)

current_letter = tkinter.IntVar(0)

b = MyButton(root)
l = MyLabel(root)
```

Note that I have removed class `Letter` as it is not necessary.  I also rename class `Label` and `Button` to `MyLabel` and `MyButton` respectively as they are classes in tkinter.