# Remove label text and set new label text on button click

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have made a smaller program to help troubleshoot for the main program. In this program I want the previous label text to be deleted before the new label text is displayed. This is important because if you leave the old label text in the label, the text ends up overlaping eachother.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x200")

def onButtonClick():
    while True:
        answerLabel = Label(root, text=wordEntry.get())
        answerLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
        break


enterWordLabel = Label(root, text="Enter a word")
enterWordLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

wordEntry = Entry(root)
wordEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

enterButton = Button(root, text="Enter", command=onButtonClick)
enterButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: This is what happens when I enter "Goodbye" first, then "Hello"]

Comment: It has been several years since I used python, but why do you have a while statement? it appears to me that it doesn't do anything as you break it on the first run, so effectively it would work the same to take the loop out. Also, you may find your answer in this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126015/2793683

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the text on a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125842/changing-the-text-on-a-label)

Comment: *"ends up overlaping eachothe"*: You are stacking `Label`'s over an over on every `command=onButtonClick`. You have to create the `Label` **once** or `.destroy()` the previos `Label` before creating a new on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every widget has a `configure` method which allows you to change its attributes. The problem in your code is that you create new labels rather than changing the text of an existing label.

The proper solution is to create `answerLabel` once, and then call the `configure` method in your script:

```
...
answerLabel = Label(root, text="")
answerLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
...

def onButtonClick():
    answerLabel.configure(text=wordEntry.get())
```