# Label widgets are getting overwritten, how to delete

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am making a unit converter, in which the user can freely choose the units he wants and convert them.

I was making the converter for temperature units(Celsius, Kelvin and Fahrenheit), and I stumbled across an error in which the `Label` widgets are getting overwritten even though I'm trying to delete them.

Heres the function which deals with this:

```
# Phase 2
def phase_2():

    # The Subphases
    # Temp
    def temprature():

        mega.forget()

        heading = Label(root, text="Temprature", padx=40, pady=15, relief=SUNKEN)
        heading.pack()

        frameps = LabelFrame(root)
        frameps.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        def conversion():

            # Answer Box
            answer = LabelFrame(frameps, padx=10)
            answer.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=20)

            empty = Label(answer, text="Value")
            empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            # C functions
            def C_F():                 
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{(int(val.get()) * (9 / 5)) + 32}°F")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            def C_K():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{int(val.get()) + 273.15}°K")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            def C_C():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{int(val.get())}°C")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            # F functions
            def F_C():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{(int(val.get()) - 32) * 5/9}°C")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            def F_K():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{(int(val.get()) - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15}°K")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            def F_F():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{int(val.get())}°F")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            # K functions
            def K_F():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{(int(val.get()) - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32}°F")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            def K_C():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{int(val.get()) - 273.15}°C")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)

            def K_K():
                empty = Label(answer, text=f"{int(val.get())}°K")
                empty.grid(row=0, column=0)


            # C probs
            if unit.get() == "C" and u.get() == "F":
                answer.forget()
                C_F()
            if unit.get() == "C" and u.get() == "K":
                answer.forget()
                C_K()
            if unit.get() == "C" and u.get() == "C":
                answer.forget()
                C_C()
            
            # F probs
            if unit.get() == "F" and u.get() == "C":
                answer.forget()
                F_C()
            if unit.get() == "F" and u.get() == "K":
                answer.forget()
                F_K()
            if unit.get() == "F" and u.get() == "F":
                answer.forget()
                F_F()
            
            # K probs
            if unit.get() == "K" and u.get() == "F":
                answer.forget()
                K_F()
            if unit.get() == "K" and u.get() == "C":
                answer.forget()
                K_C()
            if unit.get() == "K" and u.get() == "K":
                answer.forget()
                K_K()
```

as you can see, i keep trying 'answer.forget' so that the label is forgotten, and then rewritten every time that i use the converter button, but instead, this happens:
[image: The labels are getting overlapped even tho im trying to delete them]

Comment: You can change the text of a `Label` instead of recreating it every time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125842/changing-the-text-on-a-label

Comment: @Pietro could u give an example with reference to my code?

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to build the layout once and change the values as needed, something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.count = 0

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Click the button!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.some_button = tk.Button(self, text="Click", command=self.some)
        self.some_button.pack()

        self.close_button = tk.Button(self, text="Close", command=self.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def some(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.label["text"] = f"You clicked {self.count} times."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

So when you click the `Convert` button, you should call a function in your app, and inside that you read the values and setting that you need, and update the text inside the labels with the new results.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/2237151) answer explains how to structure your app with an OOP approach, that I think is very useful as your app grows.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Labels are getting overwritten, how to delete

You had  too many duplicate `Label` widgets for every function.  So, using `.configure` will prevent overwritten.

The problem can be fixed.

```
    # C functions
    def C_F():                 
        empty.configure(text=f"{(int(val.get()) * (9 / 5)) + 32}°F")
        
    def C_K():
        empty.configure(text=f"{int(val.get()) + 273.15}°K")
        
    def C_C():
        empty.configure(text=f"{int(val.get())}°C")
         
    # F functions
    def F_C():
        empty.configure(text=f"{(int(val.get()) - 32) * 5/9}°C")
        
    def F_K():
        empty.configure(text=f"{(int(val.get()) - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15}°K")
        
    def F_F():
        empty.configure(text=f"{int(val.get())}°F")
        
    # K functions
    def K_F():
        empty.configure(text=f"{(int(val.get()) - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32}°F")
        
    def K_C():
        empty.configure(text=f"{int(val.get()) - 273.15}°C")
        
    def K_K():
        empty.configure(text=f"{int(val.get())}°K")
```