# Having the error "IndexError: list index out of range" in working with python, tkinter

Tags: python, list, datetime, tkinter, indexing

I'm new to python and I wanted to know why my program is not working. The error is "IndexError: list index out of range" for line 23
(This program is for my best friend's birthday that's tomorrow)

```
import datetime
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

t = Tk()
t.resizable(0, 0)
t.title("Sana's birthday!!!")
t.geometry('200x200')

current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
current_date_lst = current_date.split('-')

l1 = Label(t, text='Sana enter your birthday in yyyy-mm-dd format:').grid(row=1, column=1)
l2 = Label(t, text='Name of your birthday legend?:').grid(row=2, column=1)

b_date = tkinter.Entry(t)
b_date.grid(row=1, column=2)
name = tkinter.Entry(t)
name.grid(row=1, column=2)

b_date = b_date.get().split( '-' )

if current_date_lst[1] == b_date[1] and current_date_lst[2] == b_date[2]:
    age = int(current_date_lst[0]) - int(b_date[0])
    ordinal_suffix = {1: 'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd', 11:'th', 12:'th', 13:'th'}.get(age % 10 if not 10<age<=13 else age % 14, 'th')
    print(f" It's {name}'s {age}{ordinal_suffix} Birthday!")
else:
    print('Sorry, today is not your birthday:(')

mainloop()
```

The error:

```
if current_date_lst[1] == b_date[1] and current_date_lst[2] == b_date[2]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- When doing `b_date.get().split( '-' )`, no text has been entered on entry yet, so you always get an empty string, from here the `IndexError`
- `b_date` and `name` have been both gridded on row 1, column 2. Thus, even if you think you are writing on `b_date` entry, you are actually writing on `name` entry.

Second problem is trivially solved by `name.grid(row=2, column=2)`. To solve first problem, instead, you need to ensure entry is only read after some text has been written.

One possible solution: force user to push a button after having entered some text. An approach I like more: for each character entered, check if string is ok and do something if it is.

Here some sample code:

```
import datetime
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

t = Tk()
t.resizable(0, 0)
t.title("Sana's birthday!!!")
t.geometry('200x200')

current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
current_date_lst = current_date.split('-')

l1 = Label(t, text='Sana enter your birthday in yyyy-mm-dd format:').grid(row=1, column=1)
l2 = Label(t, text='Name of your birthday legend?:').grid(row=2, column=1)

b_date = tkinter.Entry(t)
b_date.grid(row=1, column=2)
name = tkinter.Entry(t)
name.grid(row=2, column=2)

t.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda e: show_string(b_date, name))

def show_string(b_date, name):
    
    b_date = b_date.get().split( '-' )
    name = name.get()
    
    if len(b_date)==3:
        if current_date_lst[1] == b_date[1] and current_date_lst[2] == b_date[2]:
            age = int(current_date_lst[0]) - int(b_date[0])
            ordinal_suffix = {1: 'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd', 11:'th', 12:'th', 13:'th'}.get(age % 10 if not 10<age<=13 else age % 14, 'th')
            print(f"It's {name}'s {age}{ordinal_suffix} Birthday!")
        else:
            print('Sorry, today is not your birthday:(')

mainloop()
```

What is happening:

- You `bind` key pressed (actually key released, to ensure you are looking for the actual entered string) to a checker function `show_string`. See how to bind events to functions in tkinter, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29211864/15981043)
- You split your string as usual
- You ensure to only continue with your elaboration if string matches a given format. Trivial approach: ensure there are at least two "-" characters. Best approach: check if string is in format "yyyy-mm-dd"
- Note that you were also printing `name`. You should print `name.get()` instead. Furthermore, you are printing it on the console, while you might be interested into [updating a label in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126015/15981043) instead

Good luck and happy birthday to your friend

Answer (score 0):

So at this line in your program: `b_date = b_date.get().split( '-' )` your GUI is not running, so `b_date` is likely an empty list.

You may need to add a `Button` to trigger the code which does this splitting, and testing.

Also note that any `print()` functions will print to the terminal and not on the GUI.